# Angular2 Typescript View not updating data after save changes and update the array (model)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular2-forms

I have parent component which call a REST api to get profile (JSON) data. the parent component pass this data to child component using input (array) to create dynamic form (input fields). All fields have been created successfully. the form is saving the data to DB using API post. 
Problem: If the user navigate to home page and come back to profile dynamic form the data value is showing with the data version before save (old version of the data). If I refresh the screen, then I can get the correct data. the view has not been updated when load the form again. I checked the log and the JSON data being returned updated, but the form is getting the previous version of the values.

Parent Html

```
 <df-profile [profileData]="profileData"></df-profile>
```

Parent Component

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService, UserService } from '../services/index';
import { ProfileModel } from '../models/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'user-profile',
    templateUrl: 'user.profile.component.html'
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    profileData: ProfileModel[] = [];
    public isDataAvailable: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        public router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
         private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.info("Starting GameDay Component ngOnInit ... ...");
        console.info(this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn());
        if (this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.getData().then(() => this.isDataAvailable = true);
        } else {
            this.authenticationService.logout();
        }

    }    

    getData(): Promise<ProfileModel<any>[]> {
        return this.userService.get.profile().then(data => {
            this.profileData = data[0]['profileList'];
        });
    }
}
```

Child Dynamic Form Html

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="form.valid && onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
        <div class="kode-team-match" *ngFor="let item of profileData">
            <ul>
                <li class="home-kode-field"><df-field [field]="item.field" [form]="form"></df-field></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
                <button type="submit" [disabled]="loading" class="kode-modren-btn thbg-colortwo"> Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
        <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
    </div>
```

Child Dynamic Form Component

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthenticationService, UserService } from '../services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'df-profile ',
    templateUrl: 'profile.form.component.html',
    providers: [ProfileControlService]
})
export class ProfileFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() profileData: ProfileModel[];
    form: FormGroup;
    payLoad = '';

    constructor(
        private pcs: ProfileControlService,
    ) {
        this.profileData = [];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //console.log('Starting form component ... ...');
        this.form = this.pcs.toFormGroup(this.profileData); 
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.userService.saveUserProfile(array)
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.isFailed = result;
            if (result === true) {
                this.service.success(this.translate.instant('register login'), this.translate.instant('register success'));
            } else {
                this.error = this.userService.errorMessage;
            }
            this.loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to see what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone help?
I don't know if I need to invoke change detection and where.